# How to add types to a file without explicitly importing them?

Tags: typescript

Say I have a function stored in a file `myfunction.ts`, like so:

```
function myTestFunction() {
    console.log('myTestFunction ran!')
}
export default { myTestFunction }
```

Can I create a seperate file that stores the type definition/JSDoc for this function, without needing to explicitely import it into `myfunction.ts`? I may be wrong, but I think in the past I've accomplished this by creating an adjacent file, `myfunction.d.ts`, and storing the type declaration in there like so:

```
/**
 * it's working!
 */
export function myTestFunction(): void
```

However, this described setup isn't working for me. Am I missing something? This file will be scaling a lot and I like to keep my type definitions away from my code to avoid clutter- as I can just hover over the function in the IDE if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `export`. Also, "I like to keep my type definitions away from my code to avoid clutter" is pretty ironic, considering the fact that means you'll have to duplicate identifiers, keep two files in sync, and fill up the directory with extra files. I'm just trying to point out issues with that. You do you.

Comment: @vr. Why remove the export?
My JSDoc documents get extensive so it's easier to read my code when they're separate. Just a preference thing.

Comment: @vr. I noticed the typo in the export, if that's what you're referring to. Just fixed it

Comment: You want an ambient declaration file, i.e., you want the declarations to "work" without having to import them. Having a static `export` disables this functionality. Yes, I know it's a preference thing. I'm just pointing out some annoyances (that I would have) with it.